# A way to align divs to background without distorting it when resizing

Tags: html, css, background, alignment

The idea is to align the orange boxes to the green text on image(will eventually be a gif), but, the only way I've managed to do it make it so when resizing the window the images get distorted, I know that the background can be set so it wont distort, but than I cant find a way to keep the boxes aligned to it when scaling

(this is the first thing I'm doing the html, kind lost tbh)

Tried other methods of setting the background, which make it scales without distorting but also makes the box totally out of position

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/1RJ0mRFC/chrome-2u6s-XTFs-UH.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#box1 {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 13vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  left: 79%;
  background: orange;
}

#box2 {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 13vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 90%;
  background: orange;
}

#box3 {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 13vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54%;
  left: 14%;
  background: orange;
}

#box4 {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 13vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 61.5%;
  left: 37.5%;
  background: orange;
}

#box5 {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 13vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 82.5%;
  left: 63.5%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<a href="#">
  <div id="box2"></div>
</a>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
<div id="box5"></div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using object-fit properties along with the object-position.

I generally use contain vs cover and make sure my body has 0 margin and 0 padding

The object-fit property defines how an element responds to the height and width of its content box. It’s intended for images, videos and other embeddable media formats in conjunction with the object-position property. Used by itself, object-fit lets us crop an inline image by giving us fine-grained control over how it squishes and stretches inside its box.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: Tried it, but with no success, can't see how to use object-fit so it makes the resizing behave differently without losing the ability to fit the divs with the background specific part

Comment: Try changing background: url to background-image: url with background-size:cover in order to stretch a background image to fill its entire window.